# Multi checks in a try catch statement - is this okay?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

Is there anything wrong with doing something like this? I am basically just trying to assert that these elements exist and if not then return false:

```
public static bool IsAllDataPresent()
{
    try
    {
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("id-a");
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("id-b");
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("id-c");
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is this is wrong then any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to try catch.

Comment: you might want to know which element didn't exist somehow and throw that as part of the exception, if its not done already.

Comment: I am fairly new to Stack Overflow, but can somebody please tell me why my original post was down voted twice?

Answer (score 3):

If there is a method that tells you what you need to know *without* throwing, then call it.

If there is not, then you are in what I call a "vexing exception" situation. The best way out of that situation is to *write the method that is missing*.

```
public static bool IsPresent(string id)
{
    try
    {
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id(id);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And now your method is sensible:

```
public static bool IsAllDataPresent() => 
  IsPresent("id-a") && IsPresent("id-b") && IsPresent("id-c");
```

Notice how when you write the correct abstraction, your method bodies get nice and concise.

Comment: The method you are looking for is `.FindElements()`. You can reduce the entire function to `return Driver.Instance.FindElements(locator).Any();` Also, I would not use `string` as a the parameter. Instead use `By` so that you aren't restricted to using this function only with IDs. The function declaration would change to `IsPresent(By locator)` and the body would be as above.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question about checking multiple things and using try-catch... there's no problem with that, other than if it does fail, you're throwing away the exception which would tell you *which* of the things was missing.

In general, if you're expecting to find elements, you should *wait* for them to exist. If they exist right now, no waiting is done.

Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, new TimeSpan(0,0,5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("id-a")));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("id-b")));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("id-c")));
return true;
```

If you don't wait, there's a risk you'll test the browser for an element which isn't there *right now*, but will exist in a few milliseconds time, and your script gives a premature, false negative, answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are `trying to assert that these` **three elements** `exist and if not then return false` you can optimize your code as per the code block below :

```
public static bool IsAllDataPresent()
{
    if(Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='id-a' or @id='id-b' or @id='id-c']")).size() != 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All the 3 elements exists")
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All the 3 elements doesn't exists")
        return false;
    }
}
```